# Is there a way to make a fragment in top-level destinations (Bottom Navigation Bar) part of the scope of a separate Nav Graph using Navigation Arch

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I have a use case where I want to make a separate navigation graph that uses one of my top-level bottom navigation fragments (Fragment X) as the home destination of my new navigation graph. The problem is that Fragment X is already part of the main navigation graph.

I want to create a scope where Fragment X is the start of a new navigation graph to use this graph as the scope for a ViewModelStore Owner within a flow of logic.